# Is it possible to get JIRA worklogs via SOAP, based on their date and/or the person who created them?

Tags: soap, jira

I have an application that uses the JIRA 4.1 SOAP API, but getting the worklogs per week for users is proving quite difficult. Currently I'm getting a list of issues via a JQL query where the current user is either the reporter or the assignee and limiting the amount somewhat with 'update >= [startdate of the week I need]'. The problem with this is that the list can grow to a completely unmanageable size when going back a few months and that in some rare cases the logger isn't listed as the reporter or assignee.

What I'd need is a way to just get a list of worklogs created by the current user, ranging from from date X to date Y. Is there any workaround to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are using Tempo Jira plugin.
There is a TEMPO API that allows you to get Worklogs easily.

Here is a detailed documentation of Tempo API - https://tempoplugin.jira.com/wiki/display/TEMPO/Tempo+API+Guide

And here is an article from Tempo blog to get you started - http://blog.tempoplugin.com/2011/integrating-atlassian-jira-using-tempo-plugin-part-1/